# Spring Roo-generated Managed Bean Aspect misses import statement when using @ElementCollection

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, aspectj, spring-roo

When generating Managed Beans with Spring Roo, Roo forgets to add `import` statements for Collections like `Set` or `Map`.

See the following example, a `Person` with one last name and multiple first names:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Person {

    private String lastName;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<String> firstNames;
}
```

When calling `web jsf all --package test.jsf` in Roo Shell, `PersonBean_Roo_ManagedBean.aj` is generated, which contains the following code:

```
public HtmlPanelGrid PersonBean.populateCreatePanel() {
    ...
    firstNamesCreateInput.setValueExpression("value", expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{personBean.person.firstNames}", 
    Set.class));
    ...
}
```

As you can see, `Set`is used (of course). But `PersonBean_Roo_ManagedBean` is missing the import statement `import java.util.Set`. The import can easily be added hitting Strg+Shift+O in Eclipse, but Roo is re-creating the file all the time, so this is really annoying.

So:

1. Is this a bug?
2. Can you think of any way to circumvent this problem, maybe telling Eclipse to add the missing import statements automatically when the file is changed?

Note: the same problem also occurs when you have a `@Embedded` user type in `Person`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. Latest release: **1.2.5.RELEASE** [rev 8341dc2]

Comment: Can you try with 1.2.4?

Comment: No - same behaviour with 1.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

The answers:

> 1. *Is this a bug?*

Yes, I think so. So, I advise you to create a ticket in [Spring Roo Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO).

> 1. *Can you think of any way to circumvent this problem...?*

Just *push-in* the method to `PersonBean.java`, so you can add the missing import. Roo will not recreate this method inside the *.aj* file if you already declare it in related *.java* file.